# Beautifying URLs with FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, seo

I am currently building a website with multiple pages and in order to beautify the site's URLs I am using addresses like `http://mydomain.com/category/item-name`

I am using MySQL tables so in order to fetch the current item from my MySQL I have two options:

1) Add the item's ID to the title: `http://mydomain.com/category/28745/item-name` (where `28745` is the ID in the table). That way I can run a query `SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID=28745` . Easy approach but the problem is that the URL is a bit uglier.

2) Fetch the item using a text search. In that case I will use the item-name as a `FULLTEXT` (using `MyISAM`) so the query will be `SELECT * FROM products WHERE item-name=some-text` .

I am trying to find out if there are any downsides to the second approach. Does using `FULLTEXT` instead of an Index on an `INT` field cost in performance? Does it really matter to search engines if the URL consists of the ID and is a bit uglier?

Thanks,

Meir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a FULLTEXT index, that's the first thing.
A FULLTEXT index is an index used for searching of the database of text. What you're doing is exact matching, you're not searching for entries.

That said, what's the downside of having an index over textual column over integer one?

First thing is the size. Integers require less storage space. Their indexes require less storage space. In order to store an integer, you need 4 bytes (2^32 is the range). To store a single ASCII char you need 1 byte. So, a word that's containing over 4 letters will take up more space than number 4.5 billion.

Second thing is that you're forced to use MyISAM if you want to have fulltext indexes for some reason. 
There are advantages and disadvantages of MyISAM over InnoDB and that's a topic well-covered here at SO.

In short - unless you have 100k+ categories and growing and unless you need advanced searching options for your categories - don't use a fulltext index, use the regular one.
Table engine is up to you to decide.
For small amount of data it will all work without any issue.

Comment: Why doesnt exact matching requite an index? What's the difference between doing a SELECT * FROM table WHERE int_index = 10 to SELECT * FROM table WHERE string_index = "hello" . Why wouldn't the second query need string_index to be indexed?

Comment: Where did I say that exact matching doesn't require an index? I said you don't need a FULLTEXT index, just a regular B-Tree one on the column you want to match against. I re-read my post and I couldn't find where I exactly mentioned you don't need an index, I even mentioned that you should use regular one over fulltext one.

Comment: oh ok, sorry. I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

string searching does impact the performance, but having friendly names also matters to the search engines and is more descriptive for the user when shared. Use index on your item-name field in the database to speed up the searching a little.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a date in your addresses instead of an ID is a cleaner approach?

---

**Edit:**

If this is just about products, I think displaying them as text like the second approach is better because you probably have unique product names in a category? And if this is not the case you can perhaps add the ID in the address:

```
http://mydomain.com/category/normal-item
http://mydomain.com/category/item-that-appears-multiple-times/1
http://mydomain.com/category/item-that-appears-multiple-times/2
http://mydomain.com/category/item-that-appears-multiple-times/3
```

Comment: @Anze Jarni: Because a date is more meaningful than an ID.

Comment: I don't think that will help in any possible way. Other than that, date cannot be unique, ID on the other hand is.

Comment: Oh, I see now that I misread it. I though this was about a blog or something, but he just wants links for *products*.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting the pagenumber in a separate field.
Forget about using a fulltext index.

Make your table like this:

```
TableURL
   pageid integer autoincrement primary key
   url varchar(1000)
   pagetext text
```

now you can just retrieve the url by doing:

```
$pageid = mysql_real_escape_string(.....);
....
SELECT pagetext from tableurl where pageid = '$pageid'
```

This will make your searches much faster, speed up your inserts and keep your db-design clean as well as prevent retrieving duplicate results.